# symfony user permission to acces to a webpage

Tags: php, symfony, twig, html

I want to make a certain twig input form on a web page available to user if he have a certain value in her database `$row['GameId'];`

so I tried to write if statement for the code like that

```
  $sqlo = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$tuser'");
  while ($row = $sqlo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $gid = $row['GameId'];

     if($gid == 0 ){
        $investor = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $user->getId()));
        $MatchP = $investor->getMatchP();
        $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $investor);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
             if(!empty($form->get('MatchP')->getData())){
                 $investor->setMatchP($form->get('MatchP')->getData());
             }
             else{
                 $investor->setMatchP($MatchP);
             }

             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
             $em->persist($investor);
             $em->flush();

             $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();


             /**
              * @Route("/siteblog_homepage/")
              */
            return $this->redirectToRoute('siteblog_homepage');
           }


     }
     else{

                ?> your value are not the right one to access to this page      <?

         }
     return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
         'form' => $form->createView(),
     ));        

    //}

}
```

but i get this error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: form
```

because this line

```
     'form' => $form->createView(),
```

so how to protect this page on the wright way ?

Comment: Put a redirect in `else` part like `return $this->redirect('yourRoute');`

Comment: @Hokusai thanks you that's worked

Comment: @Bhs yes i used redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Firstable,* you need to get outside from the while loop block, *take a look* :

```
 return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
         'form' => $form->createView(),
     ));
```

*Second :*
You'r code can return 0 ,1 or many forms ,

```
while ($row = $sqlo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $gid = $row['GameId'];

     if($gid == 0 ){$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $investor);
    /**/}
```

Take a look for every loop instruction you create a form so you don't know how many form you gonna build at the end because we dont know how many ($gid == 0 ) .
So i **suggest** to you that you render these all form to your view :

```
$forms = array();
array_push($forms,$form->createView());
return $this->render('siteblogBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
         'forms' => $forms));
```

By that way you pushed all your form into an array ,then all you need to do is to parse the array into your twig file:

```
{% for form in forms %}
    {{dump(form)}}
    {{form(form)}}
  {% endfor %}
```

wish i was helpful .

Answer (score 0):

$form only available inside if(true);

Below code return : Notice: Undefined variable: a

```
<?php

    if("2"=="1")
    {
        $a = "10";
    }
    echo $a;

?>
```

define $form outside of if condition.